# Testing code for a dynamic website

Tags: unit-testing

Our website code is written in PHP.  We have very little testing in regards to it.  Most of the pages of this website are generated from SQL queries.  What is the suggested method of testing these pages (to make sure that the expected data comes out, etc)?

Sorry, I know *how* to test.  I guess my question is, what specifically should I be testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing with PHPUnit ( http://www.phpunit.de/ ) or SimpleTest ( http://www.simpletest.org/ ). End to end testing with Selenium ( http://seleniumhq.org/ ).